# Can't activate message box with SQL data - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net, populate

I am testing my knowledge of ADO.NET and SQL and am currently just trying to do the basics. I want to read from a table and when the user clicks a button, a message box pops up with the value in the ApplicationName column.

It currently doesn't do anything when I click the button... any ideas?

```
protected void TestSubmit_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Initialize the database connector.
        SqlConnection connectSQL = new SqlConnection();

        // Send the connection string.
        connectSQL.ConnectionString = @"Data Source = localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" + 
            "Initial Catalog = Inputs; Integrated Security = SSPI";

        try
        {
            // Setup our command.
            SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inputs", connectSQL);

            // Write the stored value in the text boxes.
            connectSQL.Open();

            SqlDataReader theReader;

            theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();
            theReader.Read();
            MessageBox(theReader["ApplicationName"].ToString());

            theReader.Close();
            connectSQL.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox("Oopsie: " + ee);
        }       

 private void MessageBox(string msg)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "" + Environment.NewLine + "window.alert('" + msg + "')";
        Page.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are basically just sending "window.alert('your message');" as HTML to the browser, this wont execute as JavaScript. Do you really want it to be a "popup"? If so consider using 
RegisterStartupScript() instead of outputting the JS via a label (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx). If not then why not just set the contents of the label to your return message?

Comment: right - the problem with your implementation is that you're transmitting a fragment of Javascript without a <script></script> tag around it.  Clearly that's not going to execute the script.  The proper way to do this server-side on a postback in WinForms is to register the script using RegisterStartupScript or RegisterClientScript

Comment: DOH!!! It didn't copy over the <script>.... it's there, but StackOverflow won't let it copy over...

Answer (score 0):

Sample taken from MSDN & modified for your example

```
private void MessageBox(string msg)
{
    StringBuilder cstext2 = new StringBuilder();
    cstext2.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
    cstext2.Append("window.alert('" + msg + "')} </");
    cstext2.Append("script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, csname2, cstext2.ToString(), false);
}
```

You could also use [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) instead of [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx).

EDIT: OR the classic ASP way should also work.
I am writing this without any editor.

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>window.alert('" + msg + "');</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

It does execute actually. I use this in other code and that messagebox function works fine on other projects.

Here's what I really want to do:

```
try
        {
            // Setup our command.
            SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Inputs", connectSQL);

            // Write the stored value in the text boxes.
            connectSQL.Open();

            SqlDataReader theReader;

            theReader = theCommand.ExecuteReader();
            theReader.Read();
            TextBox6.Text = (theReader["ApplicationName"].ToString());

            theReader.Close();
            connectSQL.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            MessageBox("Oopsie: " + ee);
        }
```

Note that TextBox6 is an ASP text box on the website. Clicking TestSubmit does not show the text.